# Milliseconds to HH:MM:SS time format

Tags: python

I'm trying to add the timestamp of a video frame to its own frame name like "frame2 00:00:01:05", using `CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC` I'm getting the current position of the video file in milliseconds, what I want is to change those milliseconds to the time format "00:00:00:00:".

My code currently assigns the name like: "frame2 1.05" but ideally I would have the name like: "frame2 00:00:01:05".

Is there a library that can help me achieve this milliseconds to HH:MM:SS conversion?

```
import cv2
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
success,frame = vidcap.read()
cont = 0
while success:
  frame_timestamp = (vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC))/(1000)
  cv2.imwrite(f'frame{cont} '+str((format(frame_timestamp,'.2f')))+'.jpg',frame)
  success,frame = vidcap.read()
  cont+=1
```

Thanks!

Comment: formatting a time duration has nothing to do with UTC, so I've reworded your question. -- so you're asking how to use `divmod` to break seconds into *hours,minutes,seconds*? -- BTW, you really aren't using f-strings to their potential at all. that str(format(...)) thing is pointless. just write `f"frame{cont} {frame_timestamp:.2f}.jpg"` (if your frame_timestamp is a single number)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `divmod`. It does a **div**ision and **mod**ulo at the same time. It's more convenient than doing that separately.

```py
seconds = 1.05 # or whatever

(hours, seconds) = divmod(seconds, 3600)
(minutes, seconds) = divmod(seconds, 60)

formatted = f"{hours:02.0f}:{minutes:02.0f}:{seconds:05.2f}"

# >>> formatted
# '00:00:01.05'
```

And if you need the fraction of seconds to be separated by `:`, which nobody will understand, you can use `(seconds, fraction) = divmod(seconds, 1)` and multiply `fraction * 100` to get hundredth of a second.